# Artificially incorporate non-rigid motions in Images for generating data using Python/Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, image-processing, machine-learning, python-imaging-library

The main challenges in Medical Imaging is Data acquisition. There are different types of motions (Rigid & Non Rigid) possible during acquitions(Body movement,breathing etc).

Suppose I want to generate different types of motion artificially in an Image(eg. 3D NIFTI MRI image).

Motions can be global rigid motions or elastic deformation or bspline based local deformations. Input will be an 3D image and output will be a newly generated data incorporated the desired motion.

I was wondering if there is any package or software available to do this, but didn't find any. Using this type of feature we can validate our registration methods or simulate different deformation models.

I want some help in generating such artificial data using python or matlab for NIFTI/DICOM 3D images.

Answer (score 0):

Within Python, there are a couple options. The first is using the [pydicom](http://pydicom.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started.html) module for I/O along with numpy to represent/process the layers. In order to use this, you may additionally have to use matplotlib, scipy/scikit-image, or Pillow to visualize the input and generated output.

However there is also [VTK](http://www.vtk.org/), which comes with both a Python interface and a DICOM reader/writer. Using [vtkpython](https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/Python/) will allow you to create a fairly simple application for viewing and interacting with the data. For generating the motion layers, I think numpy may still be the best option with this route.

This page has a good introduction to using both of these methods: https://pyscience.wordpress.com/2014/09/08/dicom-in-python-importing-medical-image-data-into-numpy-with-pydicom-and-vtk/

Comment: My doubt is not related to the importing dicom images, rather how to generate nonrigid motion/elastic deformation artificially with an example in python/matlab.

Comment: this sort of idea might help https://gist.github.com/mbrucher/b135444c5ad651a660d0